# AWS glue NTLM authentication

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, ntlm-authentication

I'm trying to connect a on-prem sqlserver from AWS Glue using NTLM authentication, To do that I need to add following arguments to the connection url

```
integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM
```

But when I add them, glue thows error saying the URL is invalid.

Any insights on how to resolve this would be great.

Comment: Yep, sure seems invalid. _When using authenticationScheme=NTLM, you must specify the Windows domain by using the domain or domainName property, the Windows credentials in the user or userName property, and the password property. Otherwise, an error occurs (connection properties must be specified)._ Ref: [Setting the (JDBC) connection properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties)